# undefined variables in javascript class

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, class, ecmascript-6

I'm having trouble running and understanding classes in javascript. I am experimenting this with a simple app that I made. The end goal of it is just to grab names from a `textarea`, store that in an array, and then perform actions on it such as displaying them to the screen or shuffling them. To do this, I made 2 classes. One for storing the names to an array and then another that extends from this class to manipulate the array - just for the sake of organization. Here's my code:

**Store names to array**

```
import $ from 'jquery';

class SaveInput {

  // dom selection usually and firing events when a page loads.
  constructor(){
    this.mainText = $('.main-text');
    this.names = [];
    this.events();
  }

  //events to watch for such as click
   events() {
    // save names to array, no submit button
    this.mainText.blur(this.saveNameIndex.bind(this));
  }

  // methods to be called from events

  // save names without submitting
   saveNameIndex() {
    let namesResult = this.names = this.mainText.val().split('\n');
     return namesResult;
  }
}

export default SaveInput;
```

**Maniuplate Array**

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import SaveInput from './SaveInput';

class Display extends SaveInput {
  // dom selection usually and firing events when a page loads.
  constructor(names){
    super(names);

    this.h1= $('h1');
    this.events();
  }


  //events to watch for such as click
    events(){
    this.h1.click(this.log.bind(this));
  }

  // methods to be called from events

  //display images with names
  log () {
    console.log('test');
  }

}

export default Display;
```

It doesn't matter what I do, as you can see from my 2nd class that I was just trying to test by click an `h1` tag to console log some text. I always get the same error when the app loads:

```
App.js:10522 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined
    at Display.events (App.js:10522)
    at Display.SaveInput (App.js:96)
    at new Display (App.js:10509)
    at Object.defineProperty.value (App.js:10412)
    at __webpack_require__ (App.js:20)
    at Object.defineProperty.value (App.js:63)
    at App.js:66
```

The only thing I want from the `saveInput` class is the names array so I can pass it on and there seems to be some conflict when I extend that class. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

When you create a `Display` object, it first calls the base object's constructor.  That `SaveInput` constructor calls `this.events()` which you have overridden in the derived `Display` class.  That overridden implementation is expecting `this.h1` to be set, but it isn't set yet, thus the error you see.

I don't really understand what you're trying to do here to know what fix to suggest, but this is a timing issue based on what happens in the constructor and what the derived class is ready for.  Probably you should take some stuff out of the constructor so the object can get fully formed before you call `this.events()`.

Also, if you expect the `SaveInput` version of `events()` to get called, you need to add `super.events()` to the `Display` implementation of `events()` so the base object's version gets called too.

Comment: so i guess a better question would be, what are some best practices if i want to pass just one property? in this case, just the array, with out extending the entire class?

Comment: @user2247061 - What does "pass one property" mean?  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: suppose i changed my SaveInput class to save 2 different arrays, an array of first names and an array of last names, but only wanted to use my Display class to manipulate the last names array. is there a way to inherit just the last names array and nothing else, is that possible?

Comment: @user2247061 - I can't really say without understanding more about what you're really trying to do, but perhaps your `Display` class should not inherit from `SaveInput`, but instead could create one and store it in its own instance data and then use it for whatever you need it for.